# Freemarker: Creating Xml Node

Tags: xml, freemarker

Is it a way to create a Xml Node in Freemarker?
`<field type="select" value="country" name="country" >`

Is it a way to create a `field` node out of this Xml element? I could not find it anywhere in the freemarker documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have XML in a `String` in Java, and you want to put it in as an XML Node in the model, it shows you how in the [Freemarker documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_expose_put.html).

For some reason, the example code reads from a file.  You can also parse from a `org.xml.sax.InputSource`.  If you are starting from a `String` you can create an `InputSource` like this:

```
new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlInString))
```

If you are *in* Freemarker Template Language (FTL), and you have an XML string to parse, you will need to put a parser into your model as a tool.  In your Java model setup, you would have something like this:

```
model.put("parseXML", new XMLParserModel());
```

`XMLParserModel` is a class that you write that extends `TemplateModelEx`.  You will implement an `exec` method that takes a `String` (it will take a list, but you will grab the first entry) and returns a `TemplateNodeModel` with your parsed results.  In the FTL, it would look like this:

```
<#assign myXMLNode = parseXML(xmlString)>
```

Comment: Need a Xml Node in template itself. It s not being passed from Java source.

Comment: So you have a `String` containing XML and you need to turn it into an XML Node in the FTL?  Use the second approach.

Comment: Is it `TemplateModelException` class which XMLParserModel needs to extend?

Comment: `TemplateModelEx` not `TemplateModelException`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use jstl xml tag library.

```html
<#assign x=JspTaglibs['http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml']/>
<#assign xmlString = '<doc>text</doc>'/>
<@x.parse var="xmlDoc" doc=xmlString/>
<#-- now process variable 'xmlDoc' using jsp or freemarker -->
```